# sed - error en regex para convertir a mayúsculas texto

Tags: regex, sed

Tengo una duda respecto a cómo hacer una conversión a mayúsculas con `regex` y `sed`.
Quiero convertir el campo 'native_lang' a mayúsculas.

El CSV es el siguiente:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
5,F,29,finnish,english 
6,F,23,swedish,finnish english 
7,F,19,swedish,finnish english french 
8,F,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
9,F,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french
10,F,20,finnish,english 
11,F,26,finnish,english swedish
12,F,27,finnish,english swedish french spanish
13,F,30,finnish,english russian swedish 
14,F,28,finnish,english swedish spanish german 
15,M,34,finnish,swedish english german spanish russian 
16,F,29,finnish,english swedish french spanish estonian 
17,F,19,swedish,finnish english french korean
18,M,27,finnish,english swedish german russian spanish dutch
19,F,27,finnish,english swedish russian 
20,F,26,finnish,english swedish 
21,M,23,finnish,english swedish
22,M,30,english,finnish 
23,F,25,finnish,swedish english spanish 
24,F,21,finnish,english swedish spanish 
25,F,26,finnish,english swedish
26,M,20,polish,english spanish finnish 
27,M,25,finnish,english french
```

Es script que he hecho es el siguiente

```
sed -e 's/[0-9][0-9],[FM],[0-9][0-9],[a-zA-Z]*,[a-zA-Z]/\U&/g' file.csv
```

- Para `user`: `[0-9][0-9]`
- Luego `,`: `,`
- Después `gender`:`[FM]`
- Luego `,`:`,`
- Para `age`: `[0-9][0-9]`
- Luego `,`:`,`
- Para `native_lang`: `[a-zA-Z]*,[a-zA-Z]/\U&/g`

El resultado que obtengo es:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german
1,M,30,urdu,english
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish
5,F,29,finnish,english
6,F,23,swedish,finnish english
7,F,19,swedish,finnish english french
8,F,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
9,F,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french
10,F,20,FINNISH,English
11,F,26,FINNISH,English swedish
12,F,27,FINNISH,English swedish french spanish
13,F,30,FINNISH,English russian swedish
14,F,28,FINNISH,English swedish spanish german
15,M,34,FINNISH,Swedish english german spanish russian
16,F,29,FINNISH,English swedish french spanish estonian
17,F,19,SWEDISH,Finnish english french korean
18,M,27,FINNISH,English swedish german russian spanish dutch
19,F,27,FINNISH,English swedish russian
20,F,26,FINNISH,English swedish
21,M,23,FINNISH,English swedish
22,M,30,ENGLISH,Finnish
23,F,25,FINNISH,Swedish english spanish
24,F,21,FINNISH,English swedish spanish
25,F,26,FINNISH,English swedish
26,M,20,POLISH,English spanish finnish
27,M,25,FINNISH,English french
```

No entiendo por qué en algunos casos sí lo convierte y en otros no.
Entiendo que mi fallo está en `[a-zA-Z]*,[a-zA-Z]/\U&/g'` pero no sé qué es lo que hago mal.

De hecho, si elimino `[a-zA-Z]*` no cambia ninguno y tampoco lo entiendo.

Debo hacerlo con `sed` y en una línea.

Comment: Pues así a simple vista, porque tal como tú dices, para user has usado `[0-9][0-9]` y tus primeros 10 usuarios tienen un único dígito... ergo no entran en un regex que espera DOS dígitos. Haz el segundo dígito opcional y te funcionará bien.

Comment: @Benito-B, es decir ```[0-9][0-9]?``` ? Ejecutando de esta forma no cambia ninguno. Probando con ```[0-9]``` sí que funciona pero diría que es casualidad que no hayan problemas, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mi, este sirve

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]\,[FM],[0-9][0-9],[a-zA-Z]*,[a-zA-Z]/\U&/g' file.csv
```

Con un \ adicional despues del primer [0-9] para escapar el ,.