# sed - varios cambios en una línea

Tags: regex, sed

antes he lanzado [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495699/sed-error-en-regex-para-convertir-a-may%C3%BAsculas-texto/495723#495723) consulta y ahora quiero hacer una continuación de la misma.

Quiero hacer los siguientes pasos:

- eliminar fila si 'Gender' no es 'F' o 'M'
- si es 'F', cambiar a 'Female'
- si es 'M', cambiar a 'Male'
- cambiar a mayúsculas 'native_lang'

El csv de origen es:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
30,F,19,finnish,english swedish french spanish 
31,O,40,finnish,swedish english german russian lithuanian portuguese
32,F,22,finnish,swedish english french
```

El código que he planteado es:

```
sed -e 's/,F,/,Female,/g' -e 's/,M,/,Male,/g' -e 's/[0-9]\,[FemaleMale],[0-9][0-9],[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]/\U&/g' file.csv
```

El resultado que obtengo es:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,Male,19,finnish,english swedish german
30,Female,19,finnish,english swedish french spanish
32,Female,22,finnish,swedish english french
```

Es decir, no hace el cambio a mayúsculas.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Comment: comentas muchas cosas, pero parece que el problema es uno solo. Mejor vuelve a la pregunta inicial y clarifica allí, si no se están creando tantas preguntas parecidas que no van a ser útiles

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', el paso inicial funciona si lo aplico solamente, pero no consigo hacer que funcionen en conjunto. Hago la referencia porque igual alguien me referenciaba esa consulta para que me fuera útil. La pregunta es sólo una, pero he querido indicar que he hecho diferentes pruebas

Comment: entiendo que la parte de `sed -e 's/,F,/,Female,/g' -e 's/,M,/,Male,/g'` sí funciona, ¿no? Lo que veo es la expresión `[FemaleMale]`, que es incorrecta. Si quieres decir "algo" o "otra_cosa", debes decir `(algo|otra_cosa)`

Comment: en cualquier caso, recomiendo leer [mcve], pues ayuda a que las preguntas sean fáciles de leer y debugar

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', puedo reducir el tamaño del CSV y dejar 3 líneas, tienes razón. Por lo demás, creo que es completo y verificable como se indica. No crees?

Comment: yo creo que con las columnas relevantes debería de haber suficiente

Comment: relevante: [¿Cómo combinar dos comandos sed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/346896/83)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', editado. También he retirado las opciones probadas. En otros casos no las he indicado y me han propuesto hacerlas, pero bueno, confiaré en que no ocurra. Leo que me has propuesto ```(algo|otra_cosa)``` y había indicado que una de las opciones probadas era ```[algo|otra_cosa]``` Es cuestión del ```)``` entonces? Creo que no, al menos no en la prueba que he hecho.

Comment: sí, mira esta prueba: `echo "hola amigo adios amigo" | sed -E 's/(hola|adios)/bla/g'`. Con `[]` dices "cualquiera de estos caracteres", mientras que con `()` dices "cualquiera de estas palabras". Compara con `echo "hola amigo adios amigo" | sed -E 's/[ha]/X/g'`.

Comment: Gracias. Pues no sé qué ocurre pero con ```(``` no sale y con ```[``` tampoco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo suyo es encadenar los comandos por orden:

```sh
sed 
    # elimina líneas que no tengan M/F en 2.º campo
    -e '/^.*,[^MF],/d'
    # mayúsculas y tal 
    -e 's/[0-9]\,[FM],[0-9][0-9],[a-zA-Z]*,[a-zA-Z]/\U&/'
    # F->Female, M->Male
    -e 's/,F,/,Female,/g' -e 's/,M,/,Male,/'
```